# Why does this method of finding the equation of the tangent line to a second-degree curve work?

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry, algebraic-curves, plane-curves

Given any second degree curve with the general equation
$$Ax^2+Bxy+Cy^2+Dx+Ey+F=0$$
and a point $(x', y')$ on it, if I transform the curve equation as follows
\begin{align}
(1) &&x^2 &\to& xx'\\
(2) &&y^2&\to& yy'\\
(3) &&2xy &\to& xy' + x'y\\
(4) &&2x &\to& x + x'\\
(5) &&2y &\to& y + y'\\
\end{align}
I get the equation of the tangent to the curve at the point $(x', y')$ or if the point does not lie on the curve, I get the equation of the chord of contact (which is more general). My question is why does it work, like is there something deeper going on and are there similar transformations for higher degree curves?

Answer (score 1):

This is linked to the *duality* between lines and points in  the projective plane $\mathbf P_2$. You can take look at [Pole and Polar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pole_and_polar) on Wikipedia.

I'll add that a number of properties in projective geometry can be proved by a so-called ‘*transformation by reciprocal polars*’, considering the projective coordinates $[x:y:t]$ of a point  are the projective coordinates of a projective line, and turning a problem about points into a problem about lines and vice-versa. For instance, to prove three points are aligned, you'll show the corresponding dual lines of these points have a common point.

Comment: Where can I self learn projective geometry if I don't have much background in it?

Comment: I don't know many, but personally, I'd recommend Pierre Samuel's *Projective Geometry* (Springer).

Comment: In the Wikipedia article you referenced, the transformation is just given the way it is, my question still remains, where did it come from. There's no easy way to see it in the article

Comment: Maybe looking at the [Duality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_projective_plane#Duality) page  in `Real projective plane` pages in Wikipedia will help?

Comment: I got that but then how does duality imply those transformations, particularly, how are polar and poles related to projective duality?

Comment: @RishiRaj: I've found this very interesting Wikipedia page on [Poles and polars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duality_(projective_geometry)#Poles_and_polars).